# Remove string from the start of specific string in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string

I have an url string like this in php:

```
$string = 'test.xyz/builder-list/?price=301-500%2C501-1000&builder_country=6442%2C6780%2C6441';
```

i want to remove specific string from `price` query value in the URL string that started with `%2c. for example:

```
test.xyz/builder-list/?price=301-500%2C501-1000&builder_country=6442%2C6780%2C6441
into
test.xyz/builder-list/?price=301-500&builder_country=6442%2C6780%2C6441

test.xyz/builder-list/?price=-200%2C400-500&builder_region=1223%2C3445
into
test.xyz/builder-list/?price=-200&builder_region=12%2C33

test.xyz/builder-list/?builder_state=45%2C76&price=-200%2C400-500
into
test.xyz/builder-list/?builder_state=45%2C76&price=-200
```

i tried to use this `preg_replace` function , but it deletes all the `%2C` string

```
preg_replace('/' . preg_quote('%2C') . '.*?/', '', $string);
```

Comment: why? it's just percent encoded, just simply use `urldecode`, no need to regular expressions

Comment: here's an example https://www.tehplayground.com/3if2h2QE2iCbYPVm

Comment: @Kevin i only need the first value from the `price` query parameter in the string URL , that's why i need to replace the %2C and the rest of the value from `price` query parameter in my URL string

Comment: Just for the sake if it: I guess test.xyz/builder-list/?price=-200&builder_region=12%2C33 is a typo and should be test.xyz/builder-list/?price=-200&builder_region=1223%2C3445

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using regex, you have to capture `price` specifically and capture the former and latter parts of the delimiter `%2C` into separate regex groups and replace them. It would look like below:

```
preg_replace('/(price\=)([^&]*)%2C[^&]*/', '$1$2', $str)'
               -------- -------             ----
                Grp 1.   Grp 2.              Only grp 1 and 2.
```

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$tests = [
        'test.xyz/builder-list/?price=301-500%2C501-1000&builder_country=6442%2C6780%2C6441',
        'test.xyz/builder-list/?price=-200%2C400-500&builder_region=1223%2C3445',
        'test.xyz/builder-list/?builder_state=45%2C76&price=-200%2C400-500',
        'test.xyz/builder-list/?builder_state=45%2C76&price=%2C400-500'
    ];

foreach($tests as $test){
    echo preg_replace('/(price\=)([^&]*)%2C[^&]*/', '$1$2', $test),PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Demo:** http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f5fd3acba848bc4f2638ea89a44c493951822b80

Comment: One line without any hassle! Awesome solution!

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative from regex is to break down the query string via `parse_str`.

Use the first `strtok` to get the base url and separate it so that you can feed the query string params in `parse_str`.

After you have separated it and loaded it into `parse_str`, then you can make changes on the individual parts of the query string. If you want to make changes on the price, then manipulate it like so.

Use another `strtok` just to effectively trim characters after `,` or (`%2C`) and reassign.

Finally, reattach the query strings back using `http_build_query` concatenated by the separated base url in the earlier operation.

```
$string = 'test.xyz/builder-list/?price=-200%2C400-500&builder_region=1223%2C3445';
$base_url = strtok($string, '?');
parse_str(str_replace("{$base_url}?", '', $string), $data);
$data['price'] = strtok($data['price'], ',');
$final_string =  "{$base_url}?" . http_build_query($data);
echo $final_string;
```

Comment: thanks it works, but i came accross some issue when i have an URL string like this: `http://test.xyz/builder-list/?price=201-500%2C201-500&amp;builder_country=6356%2C6699` it will be converted into this: `http://test.xyz/builder-list/?price=201-500&amp%3Bbuilder_country=6356%2C6699` when i print in the browser it has %3B in the string

Comment: @jojo you must be double encoding somewhere, `&amp;` is for html

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = 'test.xyz/builder-list/?builder_state=45%2C76&price=-200%2C400-500';

//Separate string based on & an make an array $q
$q = explode('&', $string); 

//Go through each item in array $q and make adjustments
//if it's the price-query
foreach($q as &$item) {
    if (stristr($item,'price') !== false) {
        //Just leave left the first part of
        //this item before %2C
        $pos = strpos($item, '%2C');
        $item = substr($item,0,$pos); 
        break; //No need being here in this loop anymore
    }
}

//Implode back to original state and glue it together with ampersand
$result = implode('&', $q);
```

`$result` would contain:

```
test.xyz/builder-list/?builder_state=45%2C76&price=-200
```

Comment: ah sorry! Thanks @vivek_23 . I'll adjust

Comment: I've updated my code so now it works as I think OP would expect :-)

Comment: Hmm. I think you can also add a `break` in the `if` condition once it's done.

Comment: @vivek_23 - yes that's true! It would work anyway but it's always better to do it as right as you can :-) I added the break. Thanks again!